# How do I only enable a Safari toolbar button extension when the URL meets certain criteria ('validate' check)?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I have a Safari extension that places a simple button in the toolbar. It works fine right now, but I want to handle a 'validate' event in this way:

```
1. Button is grey/disabled
2. Listen for 'validate' event (already done)
3. Check URL to see if last four letters are .gif (can implement)
4. Enable button
```

I am working in a Global.html file and I am new to JS and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `validate` event handler, the `target` property of the event will refer to the UI element that is emitting the event -- in your case, the toolbar button. Toolbar buttons (instances of `SafariExtensionToolbarItem`) have a `disabled` property, which you can set to true or false.

Example:

```
safari.application.addEventListener('validate', function (evt) {
    if (evt.command == 'myToolbarItemCommand') {
        // `toolbarButtonShouldBeEnabled` stands for some test
        if (toolbarButtonShouldBeEnabled) {
            evt.target.disabled = false;
        } else {
            evt.target.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: And make sure this is in your global html file.